# Expander header event click

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, expander

Is possible to capture the event when the expander header is clicked (on wpf)?
Only the header, no content. 
Thanks

```
PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Expander_MouseLeftButtonUp"
```

Tried this, but it works also with content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to catch expander header click event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43756055/how-to-catch-expander-header-click-event)

Comment: why are you posting same question twice? you posted this question again here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43756055/how-to-catch-expander-header-click-event