# How to catch expander header click event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, click

How to catch expander header click event in WPF?
Thanks

```
<Expander  IsExpanded="{Binding Items[0], Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource expanderExpandedConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Loaded="Expander_Loaded" >
                                        <Expander.Header>
                                            <DockPanel  PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Expander_MouseLeftButtonUp">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Style="{StaticResource GroupStyle}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"></TextBlock>
                                            </DockPanel>

                                        </Expander.Header>
                                        <Expander.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                                                <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="Arial Nova"/>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1"/>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                                            </Style>
                                        </Expander.Style>
                                        <Expander.Content>
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </Expander.Content>
                                    </Expander>
```

I tried with this but it doesn't catch the event if I click on expander's toggle arrow

Comment: Try event [Expanded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.expander.expanded(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do.  You could add preview mouse left button down to the expander itself.  This will fire even when the toggle button is clicked.  What is the reason you don't want to do this?

Comment: @AQuirky yes, but it will fire even if the extender content will be clicked, and i don't want it.

Comment: Ok...so I have provided an answer for this situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is to define a handler for preview left mouse button up and check for the original source as the toggle button in the expander header whose name is "HeaderSite"

XAML...

```
    <Expander IsExpanded="{Binding Items[0], Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource expanderExpandedConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Loaded="Expander_Loaded"  PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Expander_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" 
              PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="Expander_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
```

code behind...

```
    private void Expander_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement fe = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
        if(fe is ToggleButton && fe.Name == "HeaderSite")
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Clicked in expander header");
        }
     }
```